# Batch file - dynamically display huge list of variables?

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a 100x100 grid of variables that are similar to this (name of variables):

1x1 1x2 1x3

2x1 2x2 2x3

3x1 3x2 3x3

And so on, all the way to 100x100. Is there an easy way to do this without having to type in echo for 10,000 variables, and just use some for loop?
Keep in mind I'm wanting to display a row of 100, then the next row of 100, so they're not all in one long list, **unless** I set the mode to 100x100? I know this is really strange, but I'm trying to see if I can make a graphing function within batch files.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

How can I use the for /L loop to echo multiple variables in one line?

```
for /L %%a in (0, 1, 5) do echo %%a
```

Desired output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Actual output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may concatenate several values in the same variable (that represent a row of values), and then just show it in a simple `echo` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get NxM dimensions from Batch file parameters
set /a N=%1, M=%2

rem Create the two-dimensional array with 4-digits random numbers
for /L %%i in (1,1,%N%) do (
   for /L %%j in (1,1,%M%) do (
      set /A "number=!random! %% 10000"
      set "number=   !number!"
      set "a%%ix%%j=!number:~-4!"
   )
)

rem Show the array line by line
for /L %%i in (1,1,%N%) do (
   set "line="
   for /L %%j in (1,1,%M%) do (
      set "line=!line! !a%%ix%%j!"
   )
   echo !line!
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test.bat 10 15
 4216 3058 9311 5626 1461  464 3926 3597 5312 5074 2797 7654 3306 5763 3359
 1203 8313 8271 3591 3588 2415 6424 9730 8095 5958 8599 3062 4165 6671 6192
 7140 9204   60 8649 9962 3374 1690 3500  331 6314 2579 3194 8451 6682 3202
 2275 6582  877 8424 3732 2152 6741 1791 2544 2979 4763 1949 3282 5284 2578
 9628 2193 4806 8505 3480 2517 6596 9029 2776 2377 6105 3007 8464 3826 2090
  281 2278 2559 7318 3207  500   98 2061 8572 4653 9646 6815 5218 2067 2512
 9862 8686 3945 5059 1191  947 9589 1983 8213 8246  408 5458 3286 7890 1280
 1297 6154 8701 5214  769 1305 1946 3172 5201 5245 2113 2865 5866 8864 6476
 1760 3050 3014 8195 1325 4029 2302 9466 5002 2622  741 8665 7090 9580 3388
 5245 7004 9264 1708 4173 9041 8462 2055 9215 3809 2362 4400 1308 3411 5677
```

Comment: This worked marvelously, so much faser than what I was trying before. I can also change the size of this grid, too. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get your desired output for your example above. Note that the quotes are not required, but recommended so that you are aware of the trailing space after %%a.

```
for /L %%a in (0, 1, 5) do <nul set/p "=%%a "
```